# Why doesn't the 'infinite scroll' stop loading content?

Tags: javascript, php

I am using an 'infinite scroll' script that keeps sending requests to the database even when there are no more records. When that happens, it reloads the last set on the page. I would like for the function to stop running when it reaches the last record on the database. I'm new to JS so this is a bit difficult for me to troubleshoot, also, I'm not using jQuery. I am doing most of the work in the PHP script.

I've been reading a lot of posts in here about 'infinite scroll' and I am unable to get how other people check the limits in JS.

JavaScript

```
function loadPosts(){
    var target = document.getElementById('PostsContainer');
    var contentHeight = target.offsetHeight;
    var yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
    var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
    if(y >= contentHeight){
        var xhr = ajaxObj("POST", "loadContent.php");
        xhr.onload = function(){
            target.innerHTML += xhr.responseText;
        }
        xhr.send("action=loadMore");
    }
}
window.onscroll = loadPosts;
```

PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_type = 'a' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 2" //Original content on page

$totalPosts = 12; (query to DB)
$max = 1;
$current = 2; //Start on record after initial content

while($current < $totalPosts){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_type = 'a' ORDER BY post_date DESC
  LIMIT $current, $max";
  $result = $db_link->query($sql);
  $posts_list += ... //Collect the data from DB
  $current++;
}
echo $posts_list;
```

No matter how many times I keep scrolling the new content keeps loading even after I run out of records in the DB. Output keeps repeating every single time I get to the bottom of the page. In this case I have 7 posts in the DB I start with 7, 6... then I keep getting posts 5-1.

Comment: It would, as your not passing up the current page, which you should increment each time it fires, not in PHP as that going to be reset each time, then in your query you use OFFSET paging.

Comment: Exactly. And maybe react to the case when there is no additional content (`xhr.responseText == ""`) to stop the automated loading.

Comment: That is what I read in a few posts, but how would JS check for that?

Answer (score 0):

So in this case what you can do,
just add one parameter in json, from `php` or `server side` which will tell, is data present or not, based on that, you can stop calling `loadPosts` function

so basically Algorithm be like,

***...php***

```
while($current < $totalPosts){
......................
......................

  if($current >= $totalPosts)
  {
     $getNext = False;
  }
  else
  {
   $getNext = True;
  }
}
```

***...javasrcipt***

```
function loadPosts(){

   if(!getNext)
     return false;
   else
   {
   ......................
   ......................
   }
}
window.onscroll = loadPosts;
```

Hope this strategy will help you

Comment: I've been trying all day to make this work and I completely broke my code. Anyhow, I am able to send a "flag" back to the JS code via the `responseText` but when I try to use `split()` on it to check for the value and stop the function from running I get into trouble. I cannot display the data anymore, maybe the way I'm splitting the data or something.